# Databinding in MFC

Tags: data-binding, mfc

I have an application that is in mfc with  a very rich domain object, but I am not sure how to setup the databinding with the cformview.  How do you deal with databinding?  Are you ussing the DDX and DDV or do you have a better trick?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [The Humble Dialog](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/TheHumbleDialogBox.pdf) [PDF] for an example of testable and well-separated databinding.